# Ranke One Update of Matrix Square Root

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

The matrix square root of $A\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ is defined to be any matrix $\sqrt{A}$ such that $\sqrt{A}\sqrt{A}=A$. Computing a matrix square root usually takes $O(d^3)$ time. Let $b\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Assuming both $\sqrt{A}$ and $\sqrt{A+bb^T}$ exists, is it possible to compute $\sqrt{A+bb^T}$ in $O(d^2)$ time if $\sqrt{A}$ is known?

Comment: Note that such a square root might not exist. For instance:
$$
A = \pmatrix{-1&0&1\\0&-1&0\\0&0&0}, \quad b = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}
$$

Comment: Thanks. Updated the question to the case where we assume $A+bb^T$ has a square root.

Comment: As [I note here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3614633/81360): if $A$ is invertible, then we have square root 
$$
\sqrt{A + bb^T} = A^{1/4}\left(I + \frac{\sqrt{1 + c^Tc} - 1}{c^Tc} cc^T\right)A^{1/4},
$$
where $c = A^{-1/2}b$.

Comment: In the notation of this post, it seems the note you refers to requires that  'A' is positive definite. Did I understand that correctly? If so, I am confused why it is needed. Maybe that is only in the case of the other question, and, for this question 'inverse' is sufficient?

Comment: Ah, I did miss that. So that said, I am not totally sure that this formula will work outside of that setting. At the very least, it should be modified to
$$
A^{1/4}\left(I + \frac{\sqrt{1 + c^Tc} - 1}{c^Tc} cc^T\right)[A^{1/4}]^T
$$
for the case that $A$ is not symmetric

Comment: Not op but A is required to be positive SEMI definite to have a square root. If it is positive definite, Ben's solution is correct.

Comment: Ben: This is definitely interesting. I think it might be modified to get a satisfactory solution.

Comment: @Alexander Let me know if you get anywhere with it!

Comment: cgss: I think there might be a difference of terminology here. I defined matrix square root as any matrix $M$ satisfying $MM=A$. Matrix square root is sometimes defined differently as the unique such matrix when $A$ is PSD. See e.g. wikipedia "Some authors use the name square root or the notation $A^{1/2}$ only for the specific case when $A$ is positive semidefinite, to denote the unique matrix $B$ that is positive semidefinite ... . "

Comment: @Alexander I think that what Wikipedia is trying to say is that most authors use the term they way you did, while some others use it for any Cholesky decomposition. For any $u \in R^d, uXu^T$ is a real number thus $(uXu^T )(uXu^T) \ge 0 \implies (uX)(u^T u)(Xu^T ) \ge 0$     but $u^T u $ is a positive number so $(uX)(Xu^T ) \ge 0$ or $uAu^T \ge 0$ where $X^2 = A$

Comment: @BenGrossmann I didn't manage to verify your formula of a square root unless A is a multiple of the identity. [This answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/33470) seems to suggest that there's no analytic expression in general. Could you please check if the formula holds and give hints on how to verify it if it does? Thanks!

Comment: @gladiego I'm not sure what I had in mind at the time; it looks like my formula is wrong